# .NET Azure Storage Client - StartCopyFromUri 403 with IP restricted token

Tags: .net, azure, storage

I have a integration with Azure Storage. I'm downloading blobs, moving them to archive folder. Authentication is done with SAS token, works fine with standard token.
But when token is IP restricted I can download a package but cannot move it around container. It throws error on StartCopyFromUri.

```
   internal void DownloadBlobPackages()
    {
        this.containerClient = new BlobClient(new Uri("token")).GetParentBlobContainerClient();

        Azure.Pageable<BlobItem> blobList = this.containerClient.GetBlobs(prefix: settings.AzureSettings.AzureUntranslatedBlobsFolder);

        if (blobList.Any())
        {
            foreach (BlobItem blobItem in blobList)
            {
                BlobClient sourceBlobClient = this.containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name);
                BlobClient tgtBlobClient = this.containerClient.GetBlobClient("arhivefolder/"+ sourceBlobClient.Name);
                tgtBlobClient.StartCopyFromUri(sourceBlobClient.Uri);
            }
        }
       
    }
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Copy operation is an async server-side operation done by Azure Storage. Since your SAS token has IP restrictions in it and it does not include the IP addresses of the Azure Storage Service from where the copy operation is being execute, Azure Storage Service is not able to read the source blob.

To fix this issue, you will need to use a SAS token without IP restriction for copy operation.

**UPDATE**

If you are copying blobs in the same container (or same storage account), then you need not specify a SAS URL for the source blob. A simple blob URL should work just fine for copy operation.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Token has IP included in it.

Comment: Copy operation is done within same container, so I guess container client and blob client are authenticated correctly.

Comment: The container client and blob client run locally. When you call `StartCopyFromUri`, a request is sent to Azure Storage Service which first sees if it can read the source blob. Considering target blob URL is a SAS URL with IP restriction, Storage Service is not able to read the source blob and hence it throws the error.